# How to use labels in java?

Tags: java, labeled-statements

I am getting error while using break statements in labels in java code. This is showing `undefined label`. It is wrong to write code like this. Please assist me in using it correctly. Thanks in advance.

```
 while (true) {
     label149: if (!localIterator2.hasNext());
     while (true) {
         i++;
         break;
         HashMap localHashMap2 = (HashMap)localIterator2.next();
         if (!((String)localHashMap1.get("name")).equalsIgnoreCase((String)localHashMap2.get("emotion")))
             break label149;
         if (!((String)localHashMap2.get("IS_paid")).equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
             break label246;
         ((HashMap)Saved.this.keynamedata.get(i)).put("is_paid", "1");
     }
     label246: ((HashMap)Saved.this.keynamedata.get(i)).put("is_paid", "0");
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Comment: Uhm, you have an extra semicolon after your first if...

Comment: Basically, don't they are horrible, horrible, horrible way to program and great indicator of a very bad design

Comment: @fge - thank u :) but removing it getting another error

Comment: I couldn't disagree more. Labels are a great way to limit the scope of variables - a stepping stone to refactoring other people's lazy coding. The more a variable's scope is restricted, the more code becomes easier to understand.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A `break` with a label is not the same as a `goto` statement. Java does not have a `goto` statement.

A label marks the statement that follows it. You can use it to break out of that statement, and only out of that statement. Control of flow will always transfer to the end of the labeled statement.

So what do you have here?

```java
        label149: if (!localIterator2.hasNext());
```

Because of the semicolon after the if, this is in fact the entire labeled statement. So your `break label149` is not within its scope at all. If you did not have that semicolon, the `if` block would include the `while`, and then the `break label149` would work. But control would be transferred to the line after the end of the `while` block.

```java
       label246: ((HashMap)Saved.this.keynamedata.get(i)).put("is_paid", "0");
```

This is the statement marked by label246. Again, the `break label246` is not inside it, so it is not in its scope, and you can`t break out of a statement you are not inside of.

Comment: Well, Java _did_ reserve the `goto` keyword... Only that it does nothing with it.

Answer (score 9):

With Break and continue, you could use label where you have complicated loops within your application. But its always advisable to avoid making use of labels as it becomes hard to read the code and resembles a bad design altogether (remember goto (still a keyword in java) in other languages?). An example of label would be like:

```
abc: for (;;) {
    for (;; i++) {
        if (i == 255) {
            break abc;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("Noww i am back");
```

This says that i need to break of loop which i have labeled as abc. So it will come out of outer for loop. If i would have omitted the abc there then it would have come out of the inner most loop i.e. the second loop from which i said it to break from. You can't expect label to be anywhere in the code.

Answer (score 4):

A label break statement terminates the current loop and proceeds to the first statement
that follows the loop that is labeled by the identifier that follows the keyword break.

Eg:

```
     for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
            {
             resume:
                for (……………)
                          {
                                 ……..
                              if (……..) break resume;
                 }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

lable in java is not same as goto in c language

in flow of program their must be first contain label246: , then you allowed to use break or continue statment .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).