# Transfer flow from for loop to switch case

Tags: java, for-loop, switch-statement

Please can someone explain to me how to transfer the flow of control from the for loop to the switch case in my code

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    String answer;
    System.out.println("Are You Sure ?");
    answer = input.next();

    if (answer.equals("y")) {
        break OUTER;
    }

}

switch(operator) {
case "add":
    result = num1 + num2;
    System.out.printf("%d + %d is equal to %d", num1, num2, result);
    break;
case "subtract":
    result = num2 - num1;
    System.out.printf("%d - %d is equal to %d", num1, num2, result);
    break;
case "multiply":
    result = num2 * num1;
    System.out.printf("%d x %d is equal to %d", num1, num2, result);
    break;  
case "divide":
    result = num2 / num1;
    System.out.printf("%d / %d is equal to %d", num1, num2, result);
    break;    
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with your current switch statement?

Comment: simply put all the lines from switch keyword inside commented else block

Comment: What do you mean by *transfer the flow of control*? what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Ignoring `OUTER` the switch will be executed `if (answer.equals("y"))` or else when `i < 3` is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For loops have a condition expression, which you're already using to bail out after three attempts. You can modify the expression to take the answer into account. Something like this:

```
String answer = "";

for (int i = 0; i < 3 || !answer.equals("y"); i++) {
    System.out.println("Are You Sure ?");
    answer = input.next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer how you can use labels in java, basically your label has to be in scope of your statement
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28381212/how-to-use-labels-in-java-code)

From your code, I assume you just want to get out of the for loop. So you can do below

```
OUTER:  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    String answer;
    System.out.println("Are You Sure ?");
    answer = "y";

    if (answer.equals("y")) {
        break OUTER;
    }
}
```