# What is "search: { ... }" / "break search" syntax officially called in Java?

Tags: java

This code is from leetcode 681's solution:

```
class Solution {
    public String nextClosestTime(String time) {
        int cur = 60 * Integer.parseInt(time.substring(0, 2));
        cur += Integer.parseInt(time.substring(3));
        Set<Integer> allowed = new HashSet();
        for (char c: time.toCharArray()) if (c != ':') {
            allowed.add(c - '0');
        }

        while (true) {
            cur = (cur + 1) % (24 * 60);
            int[] digits = new int[]{cur / 60 / 10, cur / 60 % 10, cur % 60 / 10, cur % 60 % 10};
            search : {
                for (int d: digits) if (!allowed.contains(d)) break search;
                return String.format("%02d:%02d", cur / 60, cur % 60);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Normally I will use Python to do leetcode but recently I want to practice with Java. And I notice this part:

```
            search : {
                for (int d: digits) if (!allowed.contains(d)) break search;
                return String.format("%02d:%02d", cur / 60, cur % 60);
            }
```

I have never seen such use before. I can understand what it is doing: feels like it customize a 'search' block and can break from it. And I just want to know what is the official name  of such usage in Java. Thanks!

Comment: Labelled break statement.

Comment: It looks like a "label" that can be used as a "goto"

Comment: A [labeled branching statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) (or loop).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use labels in java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28381212/how-to-use-labels-in-java-code)

Comment: Always try to make your Stack Overflow question's title descriptive enough that someone can tell what your question is about without needing to click through to read the body. Hence, the edit to replace "this" with a description of what the "this" you're asking about is.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, it does not transfer the flow of control to the label like "goto" does.

Comment: @cowlinator But you could use `goto` to transfer control - it's just not used in the example

Comment: @MadProgrammer There is a `goto` in Java, but [you cannot use it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2545103/1270789) to transfer control!

Comment: @KenY-N Honestly - personally I avoid labels and gotos in favour a more readable solutions ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This construct is called the ***'Labeled break'*** in Java.

More information can be found at

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Comment: The break isn't labeled. A block is and the break has a label. (Though I accept you link mistakenly says that it is.)

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is a [*labeled statement*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7) where the statement is a [*block*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.2) and also a [*break statement with label*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.15). You don't have a labeled `break` statement - that is legal but weird.